# Poner 0 al número de la semana en sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta que me obtiene el año y la semana de una fecha:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(sw_sowing.date),"-", WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)) AS week
FROM sw_sowing
GROUP BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
```

Lo cual me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
-------------------
|      week       |
-------------------
|   2016-1        |
-------------------
|   2016-5        |
-------------------
|   2016-10       |
-------------------
|   2016-20       |
-------------------
```

Lo que yo quiero es agregar un 0 antes a las semanas que tiene un dígito y la consulta quedé así:

```
-------------------
|      week       |
-------------------
|   2016-01       |
-------------------
|   2016-05       |
-------------------
|   2016-10       |
-------------------
|   2016-20       |
-------------------
```

He intentado lo siguiente pero no me funciona:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(sw_sowing.date),"-", LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date),2,'0')) AS week
FROM sw_sowing
GROUP BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
```

De igual manera intenté con este:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(sw_sowing.date),"-", RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)), 2)) AS week
FROM sw_sowing
GROUP BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
```

Espero me puedan ayudar o si estoy haciendo mal la consulta

Gracias

Comment: Es en MySQL, ¿verdad?

Comment: Si esta en MySQL @Garrizano

Comment: Puse respuesta pero para SQL SERVER.

Comment: Intenta de la forma en que te respondí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta cambiando la primera parte con algo así:

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(sw_sowing.date), '-',LPAD(WEEK(sw_sowing.date), 2, '0'))
```

Comment: No. no me funciona, al poner esta consulta la página se cae! :(

Comment: Ya hice otro cambio...

Comment: Acomódalo a tu consulta

Comment: Si me funcionó muchas gracias! había puesto mal la función!

Answer (score 2):

Para rellenar con ceros a la izquierda existe la función LPAD. Realmente esta función lo que hace es rellenar con el carácter indicado una cadena hasta que esta tenga la longitud configurada.

```
LPAD('dia', 8, '0');
Result: '0000dia
```

Un ejemplo de uso de la función LPAD sería:

```
SELECT LPAD("34",5,'0') FROM DUAL;
```

La salida de esta consulta es ‘**00034**‘, ya que hemos indicado que se debe rellenar con ceros a la izquierda hasta que la cadena tenga 5 caracteres de longitud.

En este caso la longitud de la cadena seria de **2**.

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(sw_sowing.date),"-", LPAD(WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date),2,'0')) AS week
FROM sw_sowing
GROUP BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
```

[LDAP MYSQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad)

[LDAP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions082.htm)

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero el enlace es para Oracle, no MySQL. Este es el enlace que quieres: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad

Comment: Si tienes mucha razón gracias por el enlace

Answer (score -1):

Hice este ejemplo, pero no estoy segura si funcione en mySQL, podrias revisarlo y darte una idea de como hacerlo en tu caso.

Espero que te sea de utilidad:

```
declare @date as datetime
set @date = '2016-12-09'

--Ejemplo con los datos obteniendo partes de la fecha
SELECT YEAR(@date) as [Año]
SELECT MONTH(@date) as [Mes]
SELECT day(@date) as [Mes]

--Ejemplo concatenandole 00 al inicio... y tomando los ultimos dos digitos
-- Dato 12 , resultado 0012, con el right tomo los dos digitos de derecha a izquierda = 12
-- Dato 3 , resultado 003, con el right tomo los dos digitos de derecha a izquierda = 03
SELECT right(concat('00', MONTH(@date)),2) as [Mes]
SELECT right(concat('00', day(@date)),2) as [Mes]

-- Sin tomar los ultimos dos digitos
SELECT concat('00', day(@date)) as [Mes]
```

Comment: Esto no funciona en MySQL.

Comment: Ok, pero se puede dar una idea, buscando las funciones equivalentes para mySQL

Answer (score -1):

Puedes optar por aplicar formato a la fecha:

*Ejemplo:*

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, sw_sowing.date, 103) AS [week]
FROM sw_sowing
GROUP BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
ORDER BY YEAR(sw_sowing.date), WEEKOFYEAR(sw_sowing.date)
```

*Anotación: te recomiendo usar otras palabras para los alias de las columnas.*

Comment: Esto no funciona en MySQL.